# How to get the related child type when the parent can have multiple child type?

Tags: django, django-models

Let's say I have 3 models like this:

```
class Parent(models.model):
    CHILD_CHOICES = (
        ('ChildA', 'Child A'),
        ('ChildB', 'Child B'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    child_type = models.CharField(choices=CHILD_CHOICES, max_length=25, blank=True)

class ChildA(models.model):
    parent = OneToOneField('Parent',related_name='child_a',blank=True, null=True)

class ChildB(models.model):
    parent = OneToOneField('Parent',related_name='child_b',blank=True, null=True)
```

When the parent is created the associated child model is created (depending on the child_type field).

How to retrieve the according Child type from a Parent in the Parent view in order to map a custom Form to the right child? (for editing the Parent and the right Child Type in the same view)

(In my real scenario I have 10 different child type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options come to mind.

1) You can use the get_model() method, which is probably cleaner, to find the correct child.

2) You can do an IF statement in the middle of of a queryset.  I have hardcoded the example, but you can probably pull the child_type variable all the way thru, and use annotate.  I'm really just showing the example for how you can break up and tweak your queries with multiple related models.

Example 1:

```
from django.db.models import get_model

class ParentForm(forms.Form):   # or view
    ***code here**

    parent_model = Parent.objects.get(pk=1)

    # Get model name from CHILD_CHOICES.
    child_relation = [k for k, v in Parent.CHILD_CHOICES if v == parent_model.child_type]

    child_model = get_model('app_name', child_relation)
    child_model.objects.all()

    ***more code here***
```

Example 2: (occasionally handy depending on your setup):

```
class ParentManager(models.Manager):
    def get_child_info(self, child_type):
        try:
            query = super(ParentManager, self).get_queryset()

            # This line only works if the models have the same fields, otherwise do the below.
            query = query.values('id', 'name')

            if child_type == 'Child A':
                # Do this if your child models have different fields.
                query = query.values('id', 'name', 'unique_childA_field')
                query = query.select_related('child_a').all()
            elif child_type == 'Child B':
                # Do this if your child models have different fields.
                query = query.values('id', 'name', 'unique_childB_field')
                query = query.select_related('child_b').all()
        except Exception:
            query = None

    return query

class Parent(models.model):
    CHILD_CHOICES = (
        ('ChildA', 'Child A'),
        ('ChildB', 'Child B'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=50)
    child_type = models.CharField(choices=CHILD_CHOICES, max_length=25, blank=True)

    objects = ParentManager()
```

then in your view or form:

```
class ParentForm(forms.Form):   # or view
    ***code here**

    child_info = Parent.objects.get_child_info('Child A')

    ***more code here***
```

Comment: I really like the get_model in my case. In my real code I was doing almost the same thing by 'hand' and it was messy. I was wondering if Django provide a way to retrieve from the Parent instance the related existing Child instance? (The view that manage the parent and all the related diffrent child need to be as much abstract as possible so it will works in all cases because the final project will have around 30 diffrent child type)

Comment: There's no easy clean way because you have the model name stored in the record of the Parent.  So you have to retrieve that first.  If your child models are very similar, you may want to make one table with additional fields that classify each child.  Not sure if that is feasible.

Comment: That was my first idea, but unfortunatly the parrent contain all the data that are the same for each child, and each child are totaly diffrent and have around 20 fields each min.